# Objective-C to Swift framework throwing function conversion

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I am using `CHCSVParser` to parse some data. It has been installed through `CocoaPods` with `use_frameworks!`. Viewing the header file, there are two functions that I can use, I want to use the one that returns an error to see if something went wrong.

```
public convenience init!(contentsOfDelimitedURL fileURL: NSURL!, options: CHCSVParserOptions, delimiter: unichar)

// This is the one I want to use as I need the error if it fails.
public convenience init(contentsOfDelimitedURL fileURL: NSURL!, options: CHCSVParserOptions, delimiter: unichar, error: ()) throws
```

The actual `Objective-C` methods of the two above:

```
- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByDelimiter:(unichar)delimiter options:(CHCSVParserOptions)options;

- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByDelimiter:(unichar)delimiter options:(CHCSVParserOptions)options error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error;
```

I am using the `error` function like this:

```
do {
    let components = try NSArray(contentsOfDelimitedURL: url, options: CHCSVParserOptions.RecognizesBackslashesAsEscapes, delimiter: 0x002C, error: ())
    // Do what ever I need to do...
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

However I assume passing `()` to the `error` param is wrong. When I run this with something I know will fail the `catch` is never being called. Unsure on how to call this function correctly?

Using Xcode 7 beta 5.

Comment: I think that function is mis-defined.  It should *either* return an error object *or* throw an exception.  There is no reason to do neither in one and both in the other...

Comment: @trojanfoe yeah maybe this is an issue within Xcode converting the `Objective-C` to `Swift syntax if there is two similar methods, one which just tacks on an error object.

Comment: This is most likely a framework bug. I had a similar problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31471788/passing-an-empty-tuple-to-error-parameter-in-swift , which I reported to Apple. It was fixed in the next beta.

Comment: @Aderstedt okay yeah seems to be the same thing, but doesn't seem to be fixed. Do you still just pass an empty `()`? I am using `Xcode 7 beta 5`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the error like this

```
var error: NSError?
var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)
```

and also i think you need to check the error object for any error rather than putting try catch

Comment: So if it returns an error object why does it also throw an exception?  It makes no sense.

Comment: That's true ... I don't know why it throws exception ... I think there might be 2 methods one with error which does not throw exception and one without error parameter which  throws exception

Comment: I have updated the question with the actual `Objective-C` methods which Xcode is then converting to `Swift`

Comment: I would suggest You check for the error and also put catch block and do the same thing in both case ... there is no harm in putting try catch and checking error at the same time

Comment: @mihirmehta it won't even let me do that. Going to chalk this up to an `Xcode beta` error :-(